# reading data from Ruby in D3 (JSON)

Tags: ruby, json, d3.js

i'm confused how to read data from ruby class.
assume i have a class, called "Points".
what i want is reading the all data from this 'Points'.
what i did is like this :

```
   var allPoints = <%= Point.all.to_json %>;
                d3.json('allPoints', 
                    function(data){ .......}
```

i dont know why but somehow d3 can't read the varable allPoints.
is there maybe something i forget to put in code?
or maybe there's another way to read all data from Ruby?

Answer (score 0):

[d3.json()](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Requests#wiki-d3_json) is used for performing an AJAX call and retreiving JSON data from a server, which is then passed to the provided callback. It appears that what you're doing is generating a page with your data embedded in the page as a JavaScript. To use this object, just use it. Use whatever code was in your callback function, replacing the name `data` with `allPoints`.